# React - Dealing with an empty array when using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have little experience in react and javaScript and am having difficulty rendering a list that is initially empty
The list should be a list of search results that will be presented to the user after clicking search but the list is not being displayed because it is empty and it is not being displayed after getting the search result.

```
export default function PesquisarDisc() {
  const [disciplinas, setDisciplinas] = useState([]);
  const [resPesquisa, setResPesquisa] = useState([]);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.profile);

  async function carregarDisciplinas() {
    const response = await api.get('disciplinas');

    return response.data;
  }

  function handleSubmit({ anoLetivo1, curso1, unidadeCurricular1 }) {
    carregarDisciplinas().then((value) => {
      setDisciplinas(value);
    });

    disciplinas.forEach((disciplina) => {
      if (
        disciplina.professor_id === user.id &&
        disciplina.anoLetivo === anoLetivo1 &&
        disciplina.curso === curso1 &&
        disciplina.nome === unidadeCurricular1
      ) {
        setResPesquisa(disciplina);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="title">Pesquisar disciplinas</div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <span>Ano Letivo:</span>
        <Input
          name="anoLetivo1"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Introduza o ano letivo"
        />
        <span>Unidade Curricular:</span>
        <Input
          name="unidadeCurricular1"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Introduza a unidade curricular"
        />
        <span>Curso:</span>
        <Input name="curso1" type="text" placeholder="Introduza o curso" />

        <hr />

        <button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
      </Form>

      <List>
        {resPesquisa.map((resultado) => (
          <li key={resultado.nome}>
            <span>{resultado.nome}</span>
            <a href="/">Lançar sumário</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're mapping on `resPesquisa`, but it's not an array; you're resetting the state value N times in the `handleSubmit`'s `forEach` to an object: `disciplina`

Comment: thanks for the tip i still don't understand but i'll try to research more about forEach and sorry for the fact that the names are in portuguese

Comment: `resPesquisa` is not an array. You are using `setResPesquisa(disciplina);` which is setting an object on `resPesquisa` within a for loop. Therefore when you try to map on `resPesquisa` is fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your loop to the `then` scope otherwise disciplinas is not defined with the latest value(you are looping before the result resolved), also use `value` instead of disciplinas, or use the callback of `setDisciplinas`

```
function handleSubmit({ anoLetivo1, curso1, unidadeCurricular1 }) {
    carregarDisciplinas().then((value) => {
      setDisciplinas(value);

      setResPesquisa(value.filter((disciplina) => disciplina.professor_id === user.id && disciplina.anoLetivo === anoLetivo1 &&
          disciplina.curso === curso1 &&
          disciplina.nome === unidadeCurricular1
      ));
    });
  }
```

Edit: Taking a look at the comments I noticed your resPesquisa is used as an array, so perhaps filtering it is better

Comment: I could understand... I still hadn't seen the code you sent
thank you very much, you helped me a lot